# Relational operators precision

Tags: c++, integer, twos-complement, relational-operators

i have a question about relational operators
are they always give correct results ?
because if we run this line of code it will result 1 instead of 0

```
cout<<(ULLONG_MAX==-1);
```

and if we keep subtracting 1 of both sides it will keep resulting 1

so this could give wrong results in our programs

what is the solution to it?

Comment: Since one is explicitly unsigned and the other is signed, what exactly is your expectation, and why?

Comment: i expect that it gives 0 
because it should be handled in the language 
if that is only the problem its okay 
but its the same with other numbers too

Comment: @Mohamad_T ???????

Comment: For fun, do this: `unsigned long long one = 1; if (one < -1) cout << "How can 1 be less than -1?\n";`

Answer (score 5):

In this comparison

```cpp
ULLONG_MAX == -1
```

You have one `unsigned long long` and one `int`. Before the values are being compared, the operands undergo [*integral promotion*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) in which the `int` is promoted to `unsigned long long`, which is like doing `static_cast<unsigned long long>(-1)` so that the two operands have a common type.

Now, an `unsigned long long` can't hold the value `-1` and it will then "wrap around" to become the largest possible `unsigned long long` - which is exactly the value `ULLONG_MAX` holds.

The comparison is therefore `true` and printing `true` will show `1` (unless `std::boolalpha` is in effect).

Comment: ok i understand now
i will make a function to handle this case
thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are looking for solutions:

Enabling warnings (`-Wall` or more specifically `-Wsign-compare` on clang or gcc) should give you a warning if you accidentally do this:

```
warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'unsigned long long' and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
```

And the fix is to make sure everything has the same type.

If you really meant to compare two objects of different types, you can use [`std::cmp_equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/intcmp) (or the [example implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/intcmp#Possible_implementation) if you can't use C++20):

```cpp
std::cout << std::cmp_equal(ULLONG_MAX, -1);  // Outputs 0
```

which directly compares the values of the integers, regardless of the type.

Comment: Cool. I had missed that `cmp_equal` and friends had appeared in the library!